# How to disable Spell Check in standalone Google Chrome App

Tags: macos, google-chrome, spell-check

Based on a website, I have created a Google Chrome App (in Chrome: **click the `⋮` button > More Tools > Create Shortcut > Open as Window**).

Inside of the Google Chrome app, I want to disable Spell Check (because it actually incorrectly marks some real words with the red underline, and I don't care to add them to the Dictionary). I don't want to disable Spell Check in the entirety of Google Chrome (the parent application). Is there a way to disable Spell Check only in the Chrome App?

I am running Google Chrome on MacOS.

Comment: Not sure the distinction you are making but near as I can tell you are basically creating a shortcut to chrome in a `windowed` view.  The underlying settings apply to thew profile whether launched from a shortcut or not.  Perhaps you can find an extension that toggles spell checking or use a different profile.

Answer (score 2):

The **Spell Check** in Chrome is a Chrome profile level setting, meaning, that it can't be turned on / off for specfic "apps"  or websites contrary as could be done with things like allowing to show notifications, share location etc.

One option is to use multiple Chrome profiles, as each profile have  their own settings.

1. Create a new Chrome profile
2. Turn off Spell Check for the new Chrome profile
3. Create the website shortcut, set it to "Open as window"

The above  has some limitations and inconvenients that might be or not relevant, as having separate sessions, i.e. you might have to sign in a Chrome extension two times, one for each profile.

**Resources**

- [Use Chrome with multiple profiles](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en)
- [Turn Chrome spell check on and off](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/12027911)

---

#### A note regarding  "Chrome App" Vs "Chrome app"

Oh! Google and their habit of use common names as product names...

*Chrome Apps* is not the same as *Chrome apps*

*Chrome Apps* are installed from the Chrome Web Store. Nowadays they only work in Chromebooks.

*Chrome apps* refers to websites that are opened as apps, similar to *Progressive Web Apps*. To make this work, the user should create a shortcut and turn on a setting, as is described in the question.

**Resource**

- [Add & open Chrome apps](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?hl=en)